# Validation does not work on click of submit : jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am knew to JQuery and I am trying to validate a simple form to start with.

The problem here is the validation does not work on click of submit. Instead I get error message :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            "name": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "email": {
                required: false,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": {
                required: "Please, enter a name"
            },
            "email": {
                required: "Please, enter an email",
                email: "Email is invalid"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aimanpanday87/hsdscmcj/

Comment: Your example is not including validation plugin. Are you sure you have it in your page as well?

Comment: have you added jquery validation plugin file ?

Comment: @Aiman please check this working fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/hsdscmcj/5/

Comment: You forgot to include the plugin:  https://jsfiddle.net/hsdscmcj/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show Below Code Edit in post code only add js links

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            "name": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "email": {
                required: false,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": {
                required: "Please, enter a name"
            },
            "email": {
                required: "Please, enter an email",
                email: "Email is invalid"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @sujal-patelThanks for your help. I added the js links and its working. But the problem is its working on js fiddle and not on dreamweaver. I have written the exact code. But js does not work .

Comment: @sujal-patelYes it shows : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at file:///D:/html/bent/New%20folder%20(2)/validation.js:1:1
   (anonymous) @ validation.js:1

Comment: @sujal-patelUncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at file:///D:/html/bent/New%20folder%20(2)/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:37
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: @sujal-patelnope console shows error in first line: $(document).ready(function () { - doing research on it

Comment: It's means jquery not found... i u sure your are added jquery.js file

Answer (score 2):

Please make your code like below or check below fiddle link:

Working Code Link : https://jsfiddle.net/hsdscmcj/9/

```
            <form id="form" method="post" action="#">
               Name
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                Email
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        "name": {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 5
                        },
                        "email": {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        "name": {
                            required: "Please, enter a name"
                        },
                        "email": {
                            required: "Please, enter an email",
                            email: "Email is invalid"
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo

                    }
                });

            });

            </script>
```

This is working please check.

Thanks

Comment: please check my code here https://jsfiddle.net/hsdscmcj/5/   it is working.

Comment: @AmanKumar why you misguiding .  this https://jsfiddle.net/hsdscmcj/5/ code is working for name and email also.

Comment: Sorry but i am not trying to misguide anyone , so please Don't be anger Thanks :)

Comment: @sagar-arora The code mentioned by him is correct. The rule "required" for email has been given false. Hence it validates only for name. But since the "label email" is shown along with the validation its seems like it validates for, both but its not.

Comment: @aman-kumar The code works find in the fiddle after adding the js link. Thanks